# Android keyboard button change

Tags: android

My layout has 4 edittext, et1, et2, et3, and et4.
I want the keyboard show "Next" button while the et1, et2, and et3 input.
And press them to change the cursor to et2, et3, and et4.
The keyboard show "Done" button while et4 was input.
And press to finish input.
Where should to modify to show the "Next" and "Done" button?

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/titleEditText"
android:layout_weight="1" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent">
</EditText>
```

My edittext part code of layout.
And in Activity only below:

```
title = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.titleEditText);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look into the imeOptions attribute for EditText. To have the keyboard display "Next" you could add in your EditText xml tag:

```
android:imeOptions="actionNext"
```

And for "Done":

```
android:imeOptions="actionDone"
```

Example:

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/titleEditText"
android:layout_weight="1" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:imeOptions="actionNext"
android:singleLine="true"
```

>

Comment: Which part? Is it displaying "Next" and "Done" and just not moving along correctly, or is it not working at all?

Comment: Could you maybe post some of your code? I'm not really sure why it's not working since it is working on my end.

Comment: I'm not sure if you posted older code without imeOptions set, but I have edited my response with code that should work.

Comment: This only works (on 4.4 at least) if you have android:singleLine="true"